# Shape of magnets in moving coil galvanometer

Tags: magnetic-fields

Why are the magnets placed across the moving coil shaped in a semi-circular way?

[image]

Comment: What would happen if they were rectangular? (But is not this museum equipment now?)

Comment: @Pieter I feel this shape ensures that magnetic field always is perpendicular to the magnetic moment vector so that the torque remains same throughout. Torque=MxB (cross product)

Comment: The field gets weaker the wider the gap.

Comment: @Pieter Didn’t get you.